# Knockout custom binding not triggering for Update to observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a simple binding test. The Init and Update are called when the page opens. But if I manually update the objervable by calling a function to do it the update method is not being called in my binding handler.

SO it starts with selectedQueue being set to 2. Clicking the button correctly selects the 3rd element in the select. But my binding handler is not being called for this change.

Is there something simple I am missing?

```
    <select id="productGroup" name="productGroupen" data-bind="value:selectedQueue, treeMenu: selectedQueue">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Group 1</option>
    <option value="2">Group 2</option>
    <option value="3">Group 3</option>
</select>

<div data-bind="text: selectedQueue"></div>

<button data-bind="click:setQueue">Set to 3</button>

    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

    <script>

        ko.bindingHandlers.treeMenu = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                alert("init")
                x = valueAccessor();
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                alert("update");
                x = valueAccessor();
            }
        };


        var Model = function () {
            self = this;

            this.selectedQueue = ko.observable(2);
            this.setQueue = function () {
                this.selectedQueue(3);

            }

        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new Model());
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was using knockout-3.4

Changing my knockout to 2.2.1 as below the issues goes away.

```
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js"></script>
```

No idea that the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The Knockout docs says:

> Knockout will call the update callback initially when the binding is
>   applied to an element and track any dependencies
>   (observables/computeds) that you access. When any of these
>   dependencies change, the update callback will be called once again.

And in your code you are not accessing the "actual observable" yet because `valueAccessor()` only gets the value passed. Therefore no dependency is created on this one and `update` will not be called.

You need to wrap your `valueAccessor()` with a `ko.unwrap` or call `valueAccessor()()` to get the "actual observable".

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    alert("update");
    x = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
}
```